# php Foreach nested loop and array reset by itself in the middle

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i have this php code, 3 foreach loops and the last one or maybe the second one is causing the array to reset at some point and i can't find why?

php code:

```
<?php
  $months = range(1,12);
  foreach($accountsubs as $subs){
        ?>
  <tr style="display:none;" class="tablerow paddingzero childoverview <?php echo $classj;?>">
    <td width="40" align="center"><?php echo $subs['codename'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $subs['subclass'];?></td>
    <?php
    $itemcodes = $db->fetch_all_array("SELECT * FROM bg_itemcodes WHERE accountclass='".$subs['ID']."' and cparent = '".$ac['ID']."' ");
    $counter = 1;
    foreach($itemcodes as $code){

        foreach($months as $ms){ 
echo $counter++;
            $makedate   = strtotime($jdate.'-'.$ms.'-1');
            $sdebits = $db->single("SELECT sum($currency) as $currency FROM bg_journal WHERE factory='$jfactory'
            AND section = '".$ac['ID']."' AND record_section !='record' AND itemcode = '".$code['ID']."'
            AND FROM_UNIXTIME(jtime, '%Y%m') = '".date('Ym',$makedate)."' AND inouts = 'out' ");


            $scredits = $db->single("SELECT sum($currency) as $currency FROM bg_journal WHERE factory='$jfactory'
            AND section = '".$ac['ID']."'  AND record_section !='record' AND itemcode = '".$code['ID']."'
            AND FROM_UNIXTIME(jtime, '%Y%m') = '".date('Ym',$makedate)."' AND inouts = 'in' ");


            $totalsdc =  $scredits[$currency] - $sdebits[$currency];
        ?>
    <td class="alignright"><?php echo correctvalue($totalsdc,$jcurrency);?></td>
    <?php
        }// foreach months
    }// foreach item codes
  ?>
  </tr>
  <?php 

    }// foreach sub class
```

and here is the view source you can see how it resets on 3rd loop however it escapes the counter on second loop.

```
<tr style="display:none;" class="tablerow paddingzero childoverview showclass_8">
    <td width="40" align="center">103</td>
    <td>Other Sales</td>
    1    <td class="alignright"></td>
    2    <td class="alignright"></td>
    3    <td class="alignright"></td>
    4    <td class="alignright"></td>
    5    <td class="alignright"></td>
    6    <td class="alignright"></td>
    7    <td class="alignright"></td>
    8    <td class="alignright"><span style="float:left; color:#444;">؋</span>1,000.00</td>
    9    <td class="alignright"></td>
    10    <td class="alignright"></td>
    11    <td class="alignright"></td>
    12    <td class="alignright"></td>
      </tr>
    <tr class="tablerow paddingzero overviewtitle">
    <td align='center'><strong>400</strong></td>
    <td style="text-transform:capitalize;">expenses <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="showclass_10" class="addplus plus">+</a></td>
        <td class="alignright"><strong></strong></td>
        <td class="alignright"><strong></strong></td>
        <td class="alignright"><strong></strong></td>
        <td class="alignright"><strong></strong></td>
        <td class="alignright"><strong></strong></td>
        <td class="alignright"><strong></strong></td>
        <td class="alignright"><strong></strong></td>
        <td class="alignright"><strong><span style="float:left; color:#444;">؋</span>-59,200.00</strong></td>
        <td class="alignright"><strong></strong></td>
        <td class="alignright"><strong></strong></td>
        <td class="alignright"><strong></strong></td>
        <td class="alignright"><strong></strong></td>
      </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;" class="tablerow paddingzero childoverview showclass_10">
    <td width="40" align="center">401</td>
    <td>Raw Materials</td>
    1    <td class="alignright"></td>
    2    <td class="alignright"></td>
    3    <td class="alignright"></td>
    4    <td class="alignright"></td>
    5    <td class="alignright"></td>
    6    <td class="alignright"></td>
    7    <td class="alignright"></td>
    8    <td class="alignright"></td>
    9    <td class="alignright"></td>
    10    <td class="alignright"></td>
    11    <td class="alignright"></td>
    12    <td class="alignright"></td>
    13    <td class="alignright"></td>
    14    <td class="alignright"></td>
    15    <td class="alignright"></td>
    16    <td class="alignright"></td>
    17    <td class="alignright"></td>
    18    <td class="alignright"></td>
    19    <td class="alignright"></td>
    20    <td class="alignright"><span style="float:left; color:#444;">؋</span>-58,900.00</td>
    21    <td class="alignright"></td>
    22    <td class="alignright"></td>
    23    <td class="alignright"></td>
    24    <td class="alignright"></td>
      </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;" class="tablerow paddingzero childoverview showclass_10">
    <td width="40" align="center">402</td>
    <td>Office Supplies</td>
    1    <td class="alignright"></td>
    2    <td class="alignright"></td>
    3    <td class="alignright"></td>
    4    <td class="alignright"></td>
    5    <td class="alignright"></td>
    6    <td class="alignright"></td>
    7    <td class="alignright"></td>
    8    <td class="alignright"><span style="float:left; color:#444;">؋</span>-200.00</td>
    9    <td class="alignright"></td>
    10    <td class="alignright"></td>
    11    <td class="alignright"></td>
    12    <td class="alignright"></td>
      </tr>
```

[image: resulting this]

Comment: Where is `$months` defined?

Comment: $months = range(1,12);

Comment: Bit hard to debug without knowing what the data structure is actually like, for all we know it's doing exactly as it should.

Comment: why does it go 24 times instead of 12 ?

Comment: Might want to have a look at `$itemcodes` because it's being looped twice, which is why it's going up to 24. The counter is only reset after `$itemcodes` has finished looping. Again hard to see without knowing the data

Comment: $itemcodes includes these <td width="40" align="center">401</td>
    <td>Raw Materials</td> and  <td width="40" align="center">401</td>
    <td>Raw Materials</td>

Comment: cant help you bud without seeing the array your pulling from. Also create a new page where you can do a clean foreach and see what your doing wrong.  I really hate seeing html, php and sql mixed like that, avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as array reset that is occurring here. If you inspect your code then you can clearly see that the variable `$counter` is being initialized/reinitialized before the itemcode. Hence, the logical explanation will be that the sub category `Raw Materials` return two object for this query:

```
$itemcodes = $db->fetch_all_array("SELECT * FROM bg_itemcodes WHERE accountclass='".$subs['ID']."' and cparent = '".$ac['ID']."' ");
```

ie. you get 2*12 time increment for `$counter` which is equal to 24.

You might want to group each expense by their item code as well as you do for subcategory.

Comment: They are all unique columns i don't think it might require to be grouped, where do you think should i place the counter to see a better results?

Comment: attached a photo the question, the foreach loop and all works fine for all other items but just on that row it goes 2 times...

Comment: @codedudey If you're too lazy to debug with the info we've given you, then just set the `$counter` inside the `$itemcodes` foreach loop.